# SQL-only find time and not date in Access Date/Time field

Tags: sql, ms-access

In an Access database table some Date/Time data has corrupted and now only shows a time e.g. 15:15. Is there any SQL that will allow me to select records which only have the time data and **not** any date data in?

i have tried this, but it doesn't work

```
select datetimefield
from table
WHERE IsDate(datetimefield) = 0
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Good question, I am importing the data from access into SQL Server,  so actually it will SQL in Access

Comment: Is this just a formatting issue? i.e - are all of the fields only showing time? Is there a trend in the data that you can identify to narrow down this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access does not have separate `Date` and `Time` column (field) types, so it does two things to "help" users work with "dates" and "times":

1. Date/Time values where the time is exactly midnight will *by default* be displayed as just the date.
2. Date/Time values where the date part is 1899-12-30 will *by default* be displayed as just the time.

In these special cases the full Date/Time information can be displayed by specifically formatting the value (using the `.Format` properties of fields or controls, or by using the `Format()` function).

So, to select Date/Time values that *look like* they only contain times you would do

```sql
SELECT datetimevalue
FROM tablename
WHERE datetimevalue >= #1899-12-30# AND datetimevalue < #1899-12-31#
```

Comment: +1 Great find, Gord. Did Microsoft cite that discrepancy? I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @OverMind I don't recall seeing any official documentation from Microsoft regarding the default formatting behaviour, but then again I've never really gone looking for it. As for 1899-12-30 being "magic" because it is the date corresponding to `CDate(0)`, it's been mentioned in various places over the years.