# How to add an HH:MM time value to an Access database?

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I want to add time only as HH:MM to MS Access in Delphi.
It is shown as '21:21:00' in the Access table but it shows up as '30.12.1899 21:21:00' in my dbgrid.

```
ADOTable1.Active:=FALSE;
ADOTAble1.Open;
ADOTable1.Insert;
ADOTable1time.Value:=Strtotime(MaskEdit1.Text);
ADOTable1.post;
ADOTable1.Active:=TRUE;
```

Note: I changed editmask option to short time of TMaskEdit1
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is correctly stored, it's just not displayed as you would like.
The Date/Time in Access as the Delphi `TDateTime` is storing casually spoken 
the date in the integer part and the time in the fractional part.

To get the Time shown as desired just set the `DisplayFormat` property of your field to `hh:nn:ss`.

In the pictures below you can see the always same field formatted, not formatted  and as float.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to tweak the formatting for that column of your dbgrid to only show the time component. Access only has a `Date/Time` column type (it does not have separate `Date` and `Time` column types) so a `Date/Time` value entered without a date part is stored as `1899-12-30 hh:mm:ss`. If you are only interested in the time part then you just need to format the dbgrid column appropriately. (Access automatically does that for you in its own controls, ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26587881/2144390).)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programatically, **after** you open the dataset:

```
TDateTimeField (FieldByName ('Time')).DisplayFormat:='HH:mm';
```