# MS Access table excluding hour 00

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a table where the values are on the same row, but different column, as a specific date and time.

**Old table**

> YYYY-MM-DD hh:00:01; Value 1
>
> YYYY-MM-DD hh:00:02; Value 2

And where the new table will group and take the average of the values assigned to the same hour.

**New table**

> YYYY-MM-DD 01:00; Avg(Value 1 and Value 2)

The SQL code in VBA works just fine but skips writing the hour and minutes associated to 00:00

**Example**

> 2016-12-05 23:00; 56
>
> 2016-12-06; 68
>
> 2016-12-06 01:00; 70

Could anyone tell me why it does that and maybe point out the error in the code?

**Goal**

> 2016-12-05 23:00; 56
>
> 2016-12-06 00:00; 68
>
> 2016-12-06 01:00; 70

**Code**

```
Sql = "INSERT INTO LoggedData ( Date, Value ) "

Sql = Sql & "SELECT Format([Date],'yyyy/mm/dd hh') & ':00' AS wDate, Avg(tmp_LoggedData.Value) AS wValue"

Sql = Sql & "FROM tmp_LoggedData "

Sql = Sql & "WHERE Format([Date], 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm')"

Sql = Sql & "GROUP BY Format([Date],'yyyy/mm/dd hh') & ':00';"
```

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the default date/time formatting in Access. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26587881/2144390) for details.

Comment: Ok! I thought that by wiriting format([Date], yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm) I would include midnight. But still, it doesn't really do that

Comment: What I suspect is happening: Your `Format` function is creating a date/time string that explicitly includes a time component of '00:00'. That is being parsed into a true Date/Time value and inserted into the new table. Then, when you are looking at the values in the new table you are seeing the Access default date/time format, which is to omit the time component when the time is exactly midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Break out the date and the hour as separate columns, then group on them... Use this as a subquery for your insert

```
insert into LoggedData (Date, Value)
select TheDate + timevalue(TheTime + "00:00"), AvgValue
from (
      select format([Date],"YYYY-MM-DD") as TheDate,
             hour([Date]) as TheHour,
             avg(tmp_LoggedData.Value) as AvgValue
      from tmp_LoggedData
      group by format([Date],"YYYY-MM-DD"), hour([Date])
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *where* clause doesn't make sense and you miss a space, so try this:

```
Sql = "INSERT INTO LoggedData ( [Date], Value ) "
Sql = Sql & "SELECT Format([Date],'yyyy/mm/dd hh:00') AS wDate, Avg(tmp_LoggedData.Value) AS wValue "
Sql = Sql & "FROM tmp_LoggedData "
Sql = Sql & "GROUP BY Format([Date],'yyyy/mm/dd hh:00');"
```

**Example Output:**

```
Date                AvgValue
2012-01-03 00:00    8
2012-01-03 01:00    3
2012-01-03 02:00    5
2013-03-04 00:00    5
2013-03-04 05:00    4
```

Comment: Thank you! But still, the midnight hour is still missing, I think that I need to include something in format

Comment: Strange. It is not missing here. Are you applying other formatting later?

Comment: In your test case is LoggedData.Date a `Date/Time` column or a `Text` column? (Related to my 2nd comment to the question for a `Date/Time` column.)

Comment: It was a text coulmn, in the raw-data table, in the format YYYY.MM.DD hh.mm:ss that I converted to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss by using split. I think it is a Date/Time column now because when I try to change the midnight time to YYYY-MM-DD 00:00 manually, it goes back but when I enter 24:00 it says that it is not compatible to the Date/Time format

Comment: Think? That is very easy to verify when you go to table design. But it is correct that 24:00 is not a valid time value.