# pyodbc returns extra decimal places for MS Access Double/Single fields

Tags: ms-access, floating-point, format, pyodbc

When I'm fetching data from my access database with pyodbc, it returns false format for float, date, or integers.

For example:

These values
[image]

Are returned like this [image]

I've been searching for a long time now, I think it comes from the ODBC Driver used, but realy, I have no clue.

Another example would be a date like "21/01/2021" of type DATE in my MS Access DB, will be returned as a datetime in chinese or korean format YYYY-mm-dd H:m:s.

Comment: For the floating-point column: open the database in Access, open the table in Design View and look at the properties of the field. Are the "Format" and/or "Decimal Places" properties different from the defaults as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFSSO.png)?

Comment: As for date/time columns see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26587881/2144390).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, yes it is different from your screen, it is set to "Format: Fixed" and "Decimals: 2" or 4 following the format needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating-point columns (`Numeric(Double)` and `Numeric(Single)`) will display all decimal places in the Access UI if the field definitions in the table use the default formatting options

Format: (empty)
Decimal Places: Auto

Changing those settings to

Format: Fixed
Decimal Places: 2

will change the display format in the Access UI but the number itself will still be stored with its full precision. The ODBC driver does not pay attention to those formatting properties, so it returns the values with all available decimal places.

As for Date/Time values, the *default format* in the Access UI is to display just the date if the time component is exactly midnight. However the Date/Time value is stored with that time component (`00:00:00`) and again, the ODBC driver returns the complete value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26587881/2144390) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: The table-level settings would take immediate effect for directly opening the table in Datasheet View. However existing forms or reports may have inherited those properties from the table when those forms and reports were created, and hence may need to be updated to reflect the new settings.

Comment: Thanks to you, I figured it out, and it seems that the source software that interacts with this database is indeed writing wrong float format into the table. Thanks a lot ! Now i can move on resolving this issue !